# SyntaxError: invalid syntax - error with if statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm a semi-beginner with Python and I was wondering if anyone could help me with an issue i'm receiving?

*SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

This is on the line "`if generated_characters != < 100:`"

I was wondering how I would write this to say if the answer to `generated_characters` is over 100 to ask the user to choose a password amount within 1-99 and repeat the original question.

I presume there are also some other errors in this code that I have made - it would be appreciated if anyone could point these out but I am more than happy to try and resolve by myself as it's probably only an indentation error or typo.

Also I apologize if the code is inefficient, I am not very experienced in programming or Python in general.

Here is the code:

```
import random
import os

print("Welcome to your password generator! \n")

clear = ('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!£$%&^*()@"


def characters():

    generated_characters = int(input(
        f"How many characters would you like your {passwords_amount} passwords to be? "))

    if generated_characters != < 100:
        os.system(clear)
        print(
            "For efficiency purposes, please choose a character amount that's 99 or less.")
        characters()
    else:
        os.system(clear)

        for num in range(passwords_amount):
            password = ""
            for chars in range(generated_characters):
                password += random.choice(chars)
            print(password)


passwords_amount = int(
    input("How many passwords would you like to generate? "))

characters()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `!` doesn't negate, also `if generated_characters > 100:` and eventually you'd run into `RecursionError` so be careful with that

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it! How would I be able to avoid RecursionError?

Comment: while loop with that same condition in place of that `if` and repeat the line `generated_characters = int(input(...))` in that while loop after that print, no `else` block

Comment: SO isn't for general code feedback–for that, see [CodeReview.SE] (though make sure your code works first).

Answer (score 1):

If you logically think about it the equivalent statement to "not less than 100" would be "if greater than 99".  So this should give you what you are after.

```
if generated_characters > 99:
```

Comment: Thank you, never thought of this!

Answer (score 0):

this should run pretty smoothly. Also noticed that when you use `password += random.choice(chars)` you're only getting digits returned. Use `password += random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)` instead.

See below for entire functioning script:

```
import random
import os
import string
print("Welcome to your password generator! \n")
clear = ('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!£$%&^*()@"


def characters():
    passwords_amount = int(
    input("How many passwords would you like to generate? "))
    
    generated_characters = int(input(
        f"How many characters would you like your {passwords_amount} passwords to be? "))

    if generated_characters >= 100:
        print(
            "For efficiency purposes, please choose a character amount that's 99 or less.")
        while generated_characters >= 100:    
            generated_characters = int(input(
                f"How many characters would you like your {passwords_amount} passwords to be? (keep below 100!) "))
            if generated_characters <=99:
                for num in range(passwords_amount):
                    password = ""
                    for chars in range(generated_characters):
                        password += random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
                    print(password)
    else:
        os.system(clear)

        for num in range(passwords_amount):
            password = ""
            for chars in range(generated_characters):
                password += random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
            print(password)



characters()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it and am going to look more into the code myself to realise why certain things do what they do haha.